# Laravel 5.2 - Session::get not working

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I want to display an 'falsh-message' for the user I start to redirect him in the `routes.php` with following code :

```
Route::get('/alert',function () {
    return redirect()->route('home')->with('message', 'This is a Test Message!');
});
```

In the `alerts.blade.php` that I include in the home view I would like to read this message with:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
  Route::get('/alert',function () {
        return redirect()->route('home')->with('message', 'This is a Test Message!');
    });
});
```

My Session would be set under `storage\framework\sessions` with the following code :

```
a:5:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"8304u3fjR9EhvA88QMVGQnGcgdUcWoZj9LrHaDPh";s:7:"message";s:23:"This is a Test Message!";s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"new";a:0:{}s:3:"old";a:1:{i:0;s:7:"message";}}s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:22:"http://localhost/alert";}s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1452937821;s:1:"c";i:1452937821;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}}
```

But the Problem is that Laravel gives me no output from the message because it is empty. So maybe someone can help me.

`routes.php` :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', [
        'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index',
        'as' => 'home',
    ]);
    Route::get('/alert',function () {
        return redirect()->route('home')->with('message', 'This is a Test Message!');
    });
});
```

Comment: display the way you call the view and how you try to fetch the session ?

Comment: please show the `App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index` and any applicable blade files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert session flash data explicitly..

```
Route::get('/alert',function () {
    $request->session()->flash('message', 'Task was successful!');
    return redirect()->route('home');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `web` middleware group contains all the middleware required for sessions. Your `alert` route is in the middleware group, so it sets the session properly, however your `home` route needs to also be in the `web` middleware group to be able to read the session.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably put your `home` route inside `web` middleware in your routes.php file to make it work

Comment: So please include your routes file

Comment: added the routes.php

Comment: Make sure you don't have cached routes file in bootstrap/routes.php If you do, remove it

Comment: There is no routes.php in bootstrap/

Comment: @DanielO. Do you pass `message` variable to your Blade template?

Answer (score 0):

if you write like this :

```
Route::get('/alert',function () {
    return redirect()->route('home')->with('message', 'This is a Test Message!');
});
```

you will find a variable in view named $message; try and check `echo $message;`

It is one time use;  you can also write:

```
Route::get('/alert',function () {
    $request->session()->flash('message', 'This is a Test Message!');
    return redirect()->route('home');
});
```

It is also one time use but you need to enable the session.
If you want the message in session permanently yo can write:

```
Route::get('/alert',function () {
    $request->session()->put('message', 'This is a Test Message!');
    return redirect()->route('home');
});
```

Hope this will helps other to understand more clearly.